# How to code Epsilon constraint method in CPLEX

Tags: optimization, cplex, opl, epsilon

How to solve a bi-/multi-objective problem by the Epsilon constraint method in CPLEX using OPL?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In OPL CPLEX you can directly use [multiobjective](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoomultiobjective.mod)

```
int nbKids=200;
float costBus40=500;
float costBus30=400;
float costBus50=625;
     
dvar int+ nbBus40;
dvar int+ nbBus30;
dvar int+ nbBus50;

dvar float cost;
dvar float co2emission;
     
minimize
  staticLex(cost,co2emission);
     
subject to
{
 cost==costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30+nbBus50*costBus50;
 co2emission==nbBus50+nbBus40*1.1+nbBus30*1.2;

  40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30+nbBus50*50>=nbKids;
}

execute DISPLAY_After_SOLVE
{
  writeln("The minimum cost is ",cost);
  writeln("CO2 emission is ",co2emission);
  writeln("We will use ",nbBus40," 40 seats buses ",nbBus30,
  " 30 seats buses and ", nbBus50," buses 50 seats");
}
```

but if you prefer to use flow control you can write

```
int nbKids=200;
float costBus40=500;
float costBus30=400;
float costBus50=625;

dvar int+ nbBus40;
dvar int+ nbBus30;
dvar int+ nbBus50;

dvar float cost;
dvar float co2emission;

minimize
  cost+co2emission;

subject to
{
 cost==costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30+nbBus50*costBus50;
 co2emission==nbBus50+nbBus40*1.1+nbBus30*1.2;

  40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30+nbBus50*50>=nbKids;
}

execute DISPLAY_After_SOLVE
{
  writeln("The minimum cost is ",cost);
  writeln("CO2 emission is ",co2emission);
  writeln("We will use ",nbBus40," 40 seats buses ",nbBus30,
  " 30 seats buses and ", nbBus50," buses 50 seats");
}

main
 {
   var epsilon=0.01;
   thisOplModel.generate();
   // remove co2emission from the objective by setting coef 0
   cplex.setObjCoef(thisOplModel.co2emission,0);
   cplex.solve();
   thisOplModel.postProcess();
   var cost=thisOplModel.cost.solutionValue;
  
   // add a new constraint that cost should not move up too much
   thisOplModel.cost.UB=cost*(1+epsilon);

   // keep only CO2 emission in the objective
   cplex.setObjCoef(thisOplModel.co2emission,1);
   cplex.setObjCoef(thisOplModel.cost,0);
   cplex.solve();
   thisOplModel.postProcess();
    
 }
```

or if you want to update bounds on a constraint

```
int nbKids=200;
float costBus40=500;
float costBus30=400;
float costBus50=625;

dvar int+ nbBus40;
dvar int+ nbBus30;
dvar int+ nbBus50;

dvar float cost;
dvar float co2emission;

minimize
  cost+co2emission;

subject to
{
 cost==costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30+nbBus50*costBus50;
 co2emission==nbBus50+nbBus40*1.1+nbBus30*1.2;

  40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30+nbBus50*50>=nbKids;
  
  ctMaxCost:cost<=maxint;
}

execute DISPLAY_After_SOLVE
{
  writeln("The minimum cost is ",cost);
  writeln("CO2 emission is ",co2emission);
  writeln("We will use ",nbBus40," 40 seats buses ",nbBus30,
  " 30 seats buses and ", nbBus50," buses 50 seats");
}

main
 {
   var epsilon=0.01;
   thisOplModel.generate();
   // remove co2emission from the objective by setting coef 0
   cplex.setObjCoef(thisOplModel.co2emission,0);
   cplex.solve();
   thisOplModel.postProcess();
   var cost=thisOplModel.cost.solutionValue;
  
   // add a new constraint that cost should not move up too much
   thisOplModel.ctMaxCost.UB=cost*(1+epsilon);

   // keep only CO2 emission in the objective
   cplex.setObjCoef(thisOplModel.co2emission,1);
   cplex.setObjCoef(thisOplModel.cost,0);
   cplex.solve();
   thisOplModel.postProcess();
    
 }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Really appreciate. I have some questions. If I understand it well, there are two objectives: 1. minimising cost 2. minimising co2emission. According to the Epsilon constraint method, one of the objectives remains as objective while the other one is set as a constraint. Could you explain your code a little bit more regarding this method? I don't quite understand the code within flow control. Thanks.

Comment: I added a few comments. .UB sets the upper bound of a decision variable and setObjCoef sets the coef of a decision variable in the objective. More about scripting at https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/javascript-within-opl-cplex-alex-fleischer/

Comment: Hi Alex, many thanks for your explanations. I noticed that in the flow control code, you set the objective as cost+co2emission, why is that? Because in the Epsilon constraint method, we only optimise one objective. Thanks.

Comment: Also, according to the epsilon constraint method, we set one of the objectives as a constraint, I noticed that you did not include it directly within the constraint of the model. Instead, you include it in the Main{}, the flow control. I did not understand this. Really thanks for your answers.

Comment: minimize
  cost; will work fine too. And indeed I set the constraint by using a bound in the flow control part but I could have used a constraint too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Alex. It helps a lot. I am struggling to code Epsilon constraint tbh. I am wondering if you don't mind, could you give me the example of just minimising cost in the objective and including co2emission as a constraint? I am keen to know how to code that. Really appreciate!!

Comment: See ctMaxCost:cost<=maxint;

Comment: Thanks, Alex. I tried it in cplex, I only got one optimal solution. In this case, what if I want to find the Pareto front, how should I change the code? Thanks.

Comment: See https://community.ibm.com/community/user/datascience/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?GroupId=5557&MID=92116&CommunityKey=ab7de0fd-6f43-47a9-8261-33578a231bb7&tab=digestviewer for solution pools and pareto